# In a WordPress multisite configuration, how do I instruct WP_Query() to return posts from a sub-site?

Tags: wp-query, multisite

I have a WordPress multisite with one main site and four sub-sites. All five sites have a custom post type with the name `property`, and each site has several posts of this type.  In a PHP template on my main site, I would like to execute a `WP_Query()` that fetches all of these custom posts from one of the sub-sites (id = 4). How would I approach that?

My existing code is:

```
$blog_id = 4;
$posts = array();
switch_to_blog( $blog_id );
$query = new WP_Query(
  array(
    'post_type' => 'property',
  )
);
while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  $query->next_post();
  $posts[] = $query->post;
}
restore_current_blog();
error_log(print_r($posts,true));
```

The output written to the error log is a zero-length array:

```
[29-Nov-2018 11:33:44 UTC] Array
(
)
```

- I have confirmed that `$blog_id = 4` does indeed contain several posts of type `property`.

**Previous Stack Exchange Questions**

I found these three related questions, but none have a marked answer:

- [Get posts from the Main site to sub site - Wordpress MultiSites Network](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/306290/get-posts-from-the-main-site-to-sub-site-wordpress-multisites-network)
- [WP_Query on different site in a multisite setup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/313242/wp-query-on-different-site-in-a-multisite-setup)
- [Multisite wp_query & switch_to_blog issue](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/180424/multisite-wp-query-switch-to-blog-issue)

I found these two questions with workarounds marked as the answer, and the scope of the first is dissimilar to mine. I'd like to know if a solution exists before pursuing a workaround:

- [How would I use pre_get_posts to query another site for posts in my multisite network?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120352/how-would-i-use-pre-get-posts-to-query-another-site-for-posts-in-my-multisite-ne)
- [Querying Posts by Taxonomy From Alternate Network Site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/143437/querying-posts-by-taxonomy-from-alternate-network-site)

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `switch_to_blog()` & `restore_current_blog()` as suggested in the linked questions?

Comment: @kero Which question do you mean?

Comment: [This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/137213/108180) uses the method, but has alot of code. They reference [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/123516/108180) which suggest `switch_to_blog( ID ); /* do your stuff */ restore_current_blog();` for this kind of work

Comment: @kero Doesn't my code also follow the `switch_to_blog( ID ); /* do your stuff */ restore_current_blog();` model?